# DjangoUnicodeDecodeError codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position

Tags: python, django, apache, unicode, mod-wsgi

I have a Django Web Application running in Apache with mod_wsgi in my dedicated server with Centos 5.5.

However, sometimes (six or seven times in a day) it starts to give 500 Error for some random pages. But if I refresh the page two or three times, the page turns to normal.
But once it starts to give 500 error, every other page in my web site gives that error.

After I restarted the apache, it turns to normal for 5 or 6 hours but it never ends to give that error.

I paste the full error log below but indeed it says that 
`DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 330: invalid continuation byte.`

What may cause this kind of error and how can I detect it ? 
I may provide any additional information asap.

PS: I have same setup on my local PC(Apache-mod_wsgi) `with Win7` and I have never got this error.

```
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30] mod_wsgi (pid=30331): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/MY_SITE/django.wsgi'., referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 273, in __call__, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     response = self.get_response(request), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 169, in get_response, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 203, in handle_uncaught_exception, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 59, in technical_500_response, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     html = reporter.get_traceback_html(), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 117, in get_traceback_html, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     frame['vars'] = [(k, force_escape(pprint(v))) for k, v in frame['vars']], referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 34, in _dec, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     args[0] = force_unicode(args[0]), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]   File "/opt/python2.7.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 93, in force_unicode, referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30]     raise DjangoUnicodeDecodeError(s, *e.args), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
[Wed Sep 28 12:03:53 2011] [error] [client 46.104.250.30] DjangoUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xdd in position 330: invalid continuation byte. You passed in "<WSGIRequest\\nGET:<QueryDict: {}>,\\nPOST:<QueryDict: {}>,\\nCOOKIES:{},\\nMETA:{'CSRF_COOKIE': '041ed0a93c4b355d4861a0662d49fcb4',\\n 'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/var/www/html/MY_SITE',\\n 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',\\n 'HTTP_ACCEPT': 'application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5',\\n 'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCOD\\xddNG': 'gzip, deflate',\\n 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE': 'en-us',\\n 'HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL': 'max-age=0',\\n 'HTTP_CONNECT\\xddON': 'keep-alive',\\n 'HTTP_COOK\\xddE': 'csrftoken=10bc570d4ef77b17ce580106dafa9fb6; sessionid=60fb98634573194f7f5e18ef6014f59b',\\n 'HTTP_HOST': 'www.MY_SITE.com',\\n 'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://www.MY_SITE.com/',\\n 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B367 Safari/531.21.10',\\n 'PATH_INFO': u'/main/faq/',\\n 'PATH_TRANSLATED': '/var/www/html/MY_SITE/django.wsgi/main/faq/',\\n 'QUERY_STRING': '',\\n 'REMOTE_ADDR': '46.104.250.30',\\n 'REMOTE_PORT': '49643',\\n 'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',\\n 'REQUEST_URI': '/main/faq/',\\n 'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '/var/www/html/MY_SITE/django.wsgi',\\n 'SCRIPT_NAME': u'',\\n 'SERVER_ADDR': '93.94.251.82',\\n 'SERVER_ADMIN': 'bilgi@MY_SITE.com',\\n 'SERVER_NAME': 'www.MY_SITE.com',\\n 'SERVER_PORT': '80',\\n 'SERVER_PROTOCOL': 'HTTP/1.1',\\n 'SERVER_SIGNATURE': '<address>Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.MY_SITE.com Port 80</address>\\\\n',\\n 'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)',\\n 'mod_wsgi.application_group': 'MY_SITE.com|',\\n 'mod_wsgi.callable_object': 'application',\\n 'mod_wsgi.handler_script': '',\\n 'mod_wsgi.input_chunked': '0',\\n 'mod_wsgi.listener_host': '',\\n 'mod_wsgi.listener_port': '80',\\n 'mod_wsgi.process_group': '',\\n 'mod_wsgi.request_handler': 'wsgi-script',\\n 'mod_wsgi.script_reloading': '1',\\n 'mod_wsgi.version': (3, 3),\\n 'wsgi.errors': <mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x2b7d75ddbfb0>,\\n 'wsgi.file_wrapper': <built-in method file_wrapper of mod_wsgi.Adapter object at 0x2b7d75f12a80>,\\n 'wsgi.input': <mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x2b7d75fa0a30>,\\n 'wsgi.multiprocess': True,\\n 'wsgi.multithread': False,\\n 'wsgi.run_once': False,\\n 'wsgi.url_scheme': 'http',\\n 'wsgi.version': (1, 1)}>" (<type 'str'>), referer: http://www.MY_SITE.com/
```

The web site works seamlessly both in Apache and Django's built-in developer server at my local computer(Win7,Apache,mod_wsgi)

Comment: From the traceback that you provided it seems that it is your 500 page that raises that exception. Are you sure you're trying to solve the right problem? I'd suggest you start by testing your 500 page.

Comment: The WSGIRequest object seems to be corrupt, with entries like "HTTP_CONNECT\\xddON" instead of "HTTP_CONNECTION".

No idea why this would occur though.

Comment: @patrys actually I don't have a 500 page. Will it still cause that problem ?  @mmcnickle because the problem about `0xdd` byte and it is resolved after apache restart or page refresh, can it be related with Memory problem ? If it so how can I detect it ?

Comment: @mmcnickle There are more cases of “I” being replaced by `\xdd` in there. Looks like memory corruption, perhaps a hardware issue?

Comment: @patrys I also consider that it is a memory corruption but I don't know how I can trace it back.. Do you have any idea ? PS : I couldn't understand f “I” being replaced by \xdd. Could you explain better?

Comment: @brsbilgic If you look at the last line you pasted there is more than one instance of the letter “I” being replaced by `\xdd` character. If you want to test hardware, I recommend running `memtest` image from some bootable media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this request the client is sending a `<WSGIRequest>` with the client header `'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCOD\\xddNG': 'gzip, deflate'` in it.

If the actual encoding of the `<WSGIRequest>` is supposed to be UTF-8, then the server error is legitimate (unless this is not really what the client sent).  In UTF-8 byte value `0xdd` can only be used as the first of a two-byte character coding, in which case the next byte must have leading bits `10`.  But here the byte following `0xdd` has a leading `0` bit, so that's a decode error using UTF-8.

If the actual encoding of the `<WSGIRequest>` is something else, then the server error may not be legitimate because the client header could be interpreted as `'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODÝNG': 'gzip, deflate'` (in the case of ISO-8859-1) and ignored.

Try to identify the specific client that is sending in these requests.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but I couldn't understand how I can identify specific client that is sending specific request. On the other hand, if this is the problem why it works perfect for 6-7 hours after restarting the server? Do you have any idea?

Comment: It seems like you have some doubt that the client is really sending this.  Network traffic inspection will tell you for sure.  If the client really is sending that data, then the server is working correctly and case closed.  But if you want to debug the client, your log shows the client's IP.  If you can identify the specific process and debug from there, you can find out why this data is being sent.

Comment: If you find that the data being sent by the client does not have this distortion, then you will have to log the request at the earliest possible point in your application to confirm, and in the worst case debug Apache and mod_wsgi themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems.

(1) Something between your server and this user is mangling the header the user's sending you, turning `HTTP_CONNECTION` into `HTTP_CONNECTÝON`. This kind of thing is usually done by the more ancient and brain-dead kinds of web proxy sometimes used by misguided mobile internet providers.

In this case they're even screwing with your `HTTP_COOKIE`, which is sure to make your app non-functional anyway, even if you fix the other problem:

(2) It's a bug in Django that it gets an exception trying to read a header name with a non-ASCII/non-UTF-8 byte sequence inside. HTTP explicitly defines header names as being represented in ISO-8859-1 so Django should be using this encoding to convert the header names to Unicode and not UTF-8. All byte sequences are valid in ISO-8859-1 so there should never be a UnicodeDecodeError.

In practice there are no headers that ever use non-ASCII names, and browser handling of non-ASCII header values is a bumpy and inconsistent ride. But still, Django should allow, and ignore, the bogus headers.

Comment: I'm running into this problem now on python3.4 and django1.7. Amazing it's not fixed yet. Know of any discussions about this?